# Is there a way to propose an edit without automatically applying it?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

The site automatically applies edits to the questions when the edits are made by users with a high-enough reputation.  But there are times I am not sure if an edit I would make would be inline with the OP author's intent.  I also don't want to make an edit and, by doing so, mis-attribute to them an opinion which they don't hold.  Is there a way to make a *suggested* edit?  Or to make an edit and *voluntarily* have it become valid only after a review?
I understand that this can be done with comments. However, it can be much more difficult to convince someone to change their question than it would be to show them a change, and then have them agree that the change expresses what they meant to say, but in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to have a sockpuppet (AKA a secondary account) suggest edits.

Here are some rules you should follow with a sockpuppet if you are doing this<sup>1</sup>:

- Do **not** use it to do anything other than suggested edits.
- Do **not** review your own edits in the review queue.
- Make it clear that the account is your sockpuppet, preferably with a link to your main account.

It may be worth noting that after 500 approved edits you will no longer be able to suggest edits to posts. At that point I would recommend deleting your sockpuppet and making a new one.

1: Some of these things are not required, per say, but I would still recommend them. Some things I mentioned here *are* required, and will get you banned or suspended if you don’t follow them.

Answer (score 9):

No, once you earn the [Edit Questions And Answers](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege, you may no longer suggest edits.

When I'm attempting edits that I'm not entirely sure are in line with the OP's intent, I try to post a comment with a link to the revision history and a short explanation of how the edit can be reversed.  I think this is a good enough solution.

Answer (score 1):

One clever trick is **to submit an edit and then immediately roll it back**, accompanying it with a comment for the OP to review the edit history and decide for herself.

So,

1. the post was in state of revision #41,
2. you submit a rev. #42
3. and then rollback to rev. #41, producing rev. #43.
4. If your original edit is convincing for the OP, the only thing the OP needs is reverting it once again to revision #42, producing rev. #44.

An obvious caveat is that ["race condition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) is possible. If someone else submits an edit over rev. #43, it would require effort to merge. However, if the post is not very actively edited, you are pretty much safe.

Also, if, for some reason, OP has somehow missed your comment, your entire effort may silently get buried under a mass of other edits.

Comment: Duh!  It's so amazingly amazing, I think I'd like to steal it.  Even in case of a race condition, this just proposes another alternative version of the post.

Comment: I would think that this is a bad way to propose an edit as it would needlessly bump the question to the top of the question list when it isn't needed or wanted.